# My friends can't join my port forwarded minecraft server, despite me being able to join it locally

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have recently made a 1.12.2 forge server for me and my friends to play on. I have been using these 2 tutorials:

I have made the server and it works locally, however I cannot connect using my public IP and neither can my friends, you have to use my ivp4 IP while on my internet to join. If I try using my public IP on my internet to join, a error message appears saying:

> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information:.`

Notes:

1. I'm on windows 7
2. I'm not using ethernet
3. I have a port forwarding thing
4. My internet router is Belikn

Thanks for assisting me with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only **you** must connect via IPv4. Your friends will connect with your public ip. (ie, http://www.whatsmyip.org/)

Firstly I suggest you surely check whether port **25565** is open or not.

https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Secondly I urge you to make sure that your firewall is not blocking any minecraft components. Usually when you open up a server, it may ask you "do you want to block stuff firewall blah blah", make sure you click no.

Comment: What has IPv4 to do with this?

Comment: The user stated that "however I cannot connect using my public IP and neither can my friends, you have to use my ivp4 IP while on my internet to join"

Comment: the website contradicts what google says is my public IP. And the website also says my port is closed, how do i fix this?

Comment: Use the google one. The website says your port is closed, which means you did not port forward properly, thats why your friends couldn't join, how you fix this, well I am sure there are guides for your router

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ie6Np1Ys_4k

Comment: Thx, I will try it soon to see if it works

Comment: YES! finally, my server works, thank you so much K Split X!

Comment: Eh no problem! Glad to help (so I assume the issue was with port forwarding) ?